# How to check if a Windows version is Genuine or not?

Tags: java, c++, python, c, windows

Is it possible to check whether a Windows installation is Genuine or not programmatically?
Lets just say I want to check Windows 7 from C, C++, Java or Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this from CodeProject, in C++ ( [Check for Windows Genuine in VC++](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/233538/Check-Windows-Genuine-in-VCplusplus) )

```
#include <slpublic.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Slwga.lib")

bool IsWindowsGenuine()
{
    GUID uid;
    RPC_WSTR rpc=(RPC_WSTR)_T("55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f");
    UuidFromString(rpc,&uid);
    SL_GENUINE_STATE state;
    SLIsGenuineLocal(&uid,&state,NULL);
    return state == SL_GENUINE_STATE::SL_GEN_STATE_IS_GENUINE;
}
```

Comment: `if (expression) return true; [else] return false;` can be replaced by `return expression;`

Comment: yeah, just copied from code project, did not write it myself :D

Comment: return state==SL_GENUINE_STATE::SL_GEN_STATE_IS_GENUINE;

Comment: `SL_GENUINE_STATE` is an `enum`; using the enum name as a namespace  is a Microsoft extension (and unnecessary). Just write `return state == SL_GEN_STATE_IS_GENUINE;`

Comment: What is "55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f" ?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/getting-activation-status-information-t605565.html): Here is a vbscript that does it

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colWPA = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_WindowsProductActivation")
For Each objWPA in colWPA
Wscript.Echo "Activation Required: " & objWPA.ActivationRequired
Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objWPA.Description
Wscript.Echo "Product ID: " & objWPA.ProductID
Wscript.Echo "Remaining Evaluation Period: " & _
objWPA.RemainingEvaluationPeriod
Wscript.Echo "Remaining Grace Period: " & objWPA.RemainingGracePeriod
Wscript.Echo "Server Name: " & objWPA.ServerName
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java solution is to use `Process` to run the C++ or VBScript solution as a child process.